# MySQL log/changes table

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to know if there is a specific reason many coders create a log/changes table in MySQL to note down every change that affects the DB (for example new user creation, new entry added in X table, etc) instead of just watching what they want based on timestamps (order by time/etc to see what kind of changes have been made) on the rest of the tables.

Thank you!

Comment: If you update a record you can't see what it contained before.

Comment: All the examples I have seen are based on only adding new rows. They never edit any row. :/